# VS Code Extension stuck installing

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to install the Java programming extension in visual studio code to learn Java. However the "Language Support for Java by Red Hat" and "Debugger for Java" extensions get stuck on installing. I tried using the insider version of VS Code and reinstalling the extensions already. All the other extensions installed properly but these two. From where I've looked, the last things to try are changing the proxy settings (but I don't think that's the problem), and manually installing the extensions. [Screen shot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnM9R.png)(they've been stuck on installing for about an hour)